# Set relative paths for rmarkdown for multiple users?

Tags: r, git, r-markdown

I'm working on a collaborative report using RMarkdown and git. I am sourcing both external scripts and images. I've been able to naturalize paths in my version of documents by setting `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = normalizePath(...))`.

My issue is that, of course, this relative path is based on my own file structure. Is there a way to set my paths to the relative to the R project that isn't dependent upon each individual's machine? If not, has anyone found any workarounds for this that don't require me to copy and paste all of external code into a separate chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`here`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/index.html) package serves this purpose. Jenny Bryan provided [a longer description of its capabilities](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here).